# React Navigation - access state inside setOptions() headerRight callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, closures, react-navigation

I'm overriding [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org),  `headerRight` option with a custom Button, inside `React.useEffect`.
When pressing the button, I need to access the state `name` but the value I get is not the current one.

```js
const [name, setName] = React.useState('')

React.useEffect(() => {
  navigation.setOptions({
    headerRight: function HB() {
          return (
            <HeaderBtn onPress={submit}>
              Submit
            </HeaderBtn>
          )
        }
      : null,
  })
}, [])

function submit() {
  console.log(name) // ''
  // It always returns an empty string, instead of the
  // most recent name setted by TextInput.
  // How can I access the current name?
}

return (
  <TextInput
    nativeID="inputNameLabel"
    onChangeText={setName}
  />
)
```

Is there any way to access the current `name` without having to call `setOptions()` in each re-render? (a.k.a adding `name` to the `.useEffect` array dependency)

Comment: Why don't you want to call `setOptions` in each render?

Comment: Perhaps to avoid unnecessary to the header?

Comment: You can store the state in ref and update it to always access the latest state, but if you're not having any issues, it's premature optimization. Adding the state to dep array is the simplest solution.

Comment: @sandrina-p I am facing this same issue. According to the [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/header-buttons), `setOptions` should happen in `useLayoutEffect` although should not make any difference. Were you able to solve this issue? If so, could you post your solution here?

Comment: @Felipe, my solution was to add `name` as `useEffect` dependency. Which sucks but it was the only working solution I could find