# React Navigation HeaderLeft can't access Screen State

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

Tech stack: Expo, React Native, React Navigation

I created a basic Edit Profile screen for a user in my app and noticed that when I called an onPress function from the HeaderLeft/Right of that page to save the changes, the updated user fields tracked in state and set from a TextInput weren't being updated properly in the onPress function. Eventually I solved the issue by putting a button on the page to call the function which updated the user fields instead of calling the same function in the headers, but I don't understand why this wasn't working and how might it work.

Below are the important code snippets. Thank you! also looks similar to: [React Navigation - access state inside setOptions() headerRight callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62038483/react-navigation-access-state-inside-setoptions-headerright-callback)

```
EditProfileScreen  

const { user, setUser } = useContext(AuthContext);
const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState(user?.firstName ?? "");
const [lastName, setLastName] = useState(user?.lastName ?? "");

useEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      headerLeft: () => (
        <Pressable onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}>
          <Text>Cancel</Text>
        </Pressable>
      ),
      headerRight: () => (
        <Pressable onPress={() => saveProfile()}>
          <Text>Save</Text>
        </Pressable>
      ),
    });
  }, [navigation]);

const saveProfile = () => {
    console.log("first name user", user.firstName);
    console.log("first name ", firstName); // why is this empty?????
    console.log("last name user", user.lastName);
    console.log("last name ", lastName);
}


<TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        maxLength={25}
        activeUnderlineColor="grey"
        placeholder=""
        value={firstName}
        onChangeText={(newFirstName) => setFirstName(newFirstName)} // i also tried onChangeText={setFirstName}
      />
```

Comment: It might have something to do with the relationship between where your Header Component is rendered and where your UserContext. Provider is rendered

Comment: I remember making a custom drawer renderer where I was getting user data from a context provider and receiving context updates. After creating a ContextContainer component and rendering my navigator within it my drawer renderer stopped being stale